# Numpy incorrectly changes large floats to very small numbers when I append

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have an array of datetimes `times` and I'm appending them to an empty numpy array but first im converting them to unix time. The conversion works fine but when I add them to the array I'm getting crazy small values like e-310

```
#times = [Array of datetimes]
time_unix = np.empty(len(times))

for t in times:
    temp_time = time.mktime( t.timetuple() )
    np.append(time_unix, temp_time)
```

---

**Results**

For datetime: `2015-08-05 00:27:00`

What `time_unix[0]` should be: `1438734420.0`

What `time_unix[0]` actually is: `6.92520780368e-310`

Comment: Also `np.append` returns a new array; it does not change the array in-place.  DO NOT USE `np.append`.  It is not a clone of list append.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) if you want to insert the values. What you are seeing is the result of an [`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty)-cell (which could be anything).

Change your loop to:

```
for idx, t in enumerate(times):
    ...
    time_unix[idx] = temp_time
```

Comment: Upvotes for you both! Curious as to why numpy doesn't warn when printing uninitialized values

Comment: @wprins It just dumps whatever happens to be saved there. Quoting the documentation: "``empty``, unlike ``zeros``, does not set the array values to zero, and may therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used with caution."

Answer (score 3):

For iterative definition of arrays, start with a list, and append values to it.  Make the array at the end.  `np.append` consistently gives beginners problems, and should be banned.

```
In [393]: times =[]
In [394]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     times.append('2015-08-%02d 00:27:00'%(i+5))
     ...:     
In [395]: times
Out[395]: ['2015-08-05 00:27:00', '2015-08-06 00:27:00', '2015-08-07 00:27:00']
In [396]: dates = np.array(times, np.datetime64)
In [397]: dates
Out[397]: array(['2015-08-05T00:27:00', '2015-08-06T00:27:00', '2015-08-07T00:27:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

Look into the use of `np.datetime64`.  It makes array manipulation of data much easier.